# Generating and Verifying 1024-bit Primes in VHDL

Tags: rsa, vhdl, primes, largenumber

I'm implementing RSA encryption and need to generate random 1024-bit primes.

I can't use `INTEGER` signals because of the limit, and so I'm using `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR` and convert it to `UNSIGNED` when I need to perform arithmetic operations.

- I began by using `UNIFORM` to generate 32 random 32-bit numbers which I then copy over into a 1024-bit `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR`.
- I then set the most significant and least significant bits to '1' to ensure it is 1024-bits and odd.
- I then check for primality using an implementation of the *Miller Rabin* algorithm, which is where my problem lies.

#### This is where I generate the random primes:

```
function GEN_1024_PRIME return STD_LOGIC_VECTOR is

  VARIABLE s1, s2 : POSITIVE;
  VARIABLE random : REAL;
  VARIABLE small_random : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0); 
  VARIABLE large_random : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1023 downto 0); 
  VARIABLE prime : STD_LOGIC := '0';

begin

while prime /= '1' loop
  for I in 0 to 31 loop
    UNIFORM(s1, s2, random); 
    small_random := STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(to_unsigned(INTEGER(TRUNC(random * REAL(2147483647))), 32));
    large_random (I*32 + 31 downto I*32) := small_random;
  end loop;
      
  large_random(0) := '1';
  large_random(1023) := '1';
  prime := MILLER_RABIN (large_random);
end loop;

return large_random;

end function;
```

#### And my implementation of Miller Rabin:

```
function MILLER_RABIN (prime : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1023 downto 0)) return STD_LOGIC is
    
  VARIABLE t : INTEGER := 4;
  VARIABLE temp, r, a, x, j, n: UNSIGNED (1023 downto 0); 
  VARIABLE small_random : UNSIGNED (31 downto 0); 
  VARIABLE large_random : UNSIGNED (1023 downto 0); 
  VARIABLE s1, s2 : POSITIVE;
  VARIABLE random : REAL;

begin
    
n := UNSIGNED(prime);
    
if n MOD 2 = 0 OR n MOD 3 = 0 then
  return '0';
else
  -- calculate n - 1 = 2^s * r such that r is odd
  r := n - 1;
  while r MOD 2 = 0 loop
    r := r / 2;
  end loop;

  for I in 1 to t loop
    -- choose random a, 2 <= a <= n-2
    for I in 0 to 31 loop
      UNIFORM(s1, s2, random); 
      small_random := to_unsigned(INTEGER(TRUNC(random * REAL(2147483647))), 32);
      large_random (I*32 + 31 downto I*32) := small_random;
    end loop;

    a := large_random;
    temp := r;
    x := MOD_3(a, temp, n); 

    while (temp /= (n - 1) AND x /= 1 AND x /= (n - 1)) loop
      x := (x * x) MOD n;
      temp := temp * 2;
    end loop;
        
    if x /= (n - 1) AND temp MOD 2 = 0 then
      return '0';
    end if; 

  end loop;
      
  return '1';
end if;

end function;

function MOD_3 (a, b, c : UNSIGNED (1023 downto 0)) return UNSIGNED is

  VARIABLE x : UNSIGNED (1023 downto 0) := TO_UNSIGNED(1, 1024);
  VARIABLE y : UNSIGNED (1023 downto 0) := a;
  VARIABLE b_temp : UNSIGNED (1023 downto 0) := b;

begin

while b_temp > 0 loop
  if b_temp MOD 2 = 1 then
    x := (x * y) MOD c;
  end if; 
  y := (y * y) MOD c;
  b_temp := b_temp / 2;
end loop;
return x MOD c;

end function;
```

I convert the input to `UNSIGNED` in order to perform arithmetic operations, which seemed like it would work until I realized there will be instances in which the product of 2 values will be larger than 1024 bits.  For example, in this while loop:

```
while (temp /= (n - 1) AND x /= 1 AND x /= (n - 1)) loop
  x := (x * x) MOD n;
  temp := temp * 2;
end loop;
```

The resultant of `temp := temp * 2;` is 2048 bits.

I feel like I could get this to work by messing around with the sizes of my `UNSIGNED` variables, but I think it is getting messier than it needs to be, so I'm wondering if I am approaching this the wrong way?  **Is there a simpler way to generate 1024-bit primes?  Is there another primality test that would be better suited for my problem?**

Comment: Are you planning on synthesizing this to some actual hardware at some point, or is this only going to run in simulation?

Comment: This will only be run in simulation.

Comment: The sizes of the intermediate steps is probably going to be something you need to think about with any algorithm... I don't know this one, so I'm not sure what's supposed to happen; if overflow needs to happen you can resize() the result.

Comment: Also, if you're not planning on synthesizing, do you need to do this in VHDL? You would probably get a much bigger response on this site if you asked in a more widely-known language.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is for a course I'm taking and it requires that I use VHDL.

Comment: You need to know is the algorithm expects you to keep all bits after multiplication. I get a feeling that `temp := temp * 2` should not overflow? If it's the case, simply right it `temp := shift_left(temp, 1);`, or `temp := resize(temp*2, temp'length)`; In both case, the MSB will be dropped.

Comment: In the specific case of multiplication by 2, the product is actually only 1025 bits, and a simple test allows you to assign it to 1024 bits. x * x on the other hand... you must feed all the bits into the `mod n` operation.

Comment: I'm fairly certain I do need to keep all of the bits, as the `while` loop depends on the exact value.  I mentioned that `temp := temp * 2` was 2048 bits because the compiler gave me an error saying the rhs was of size 2048  while the lhs was of size 1024, although I see what you're saying so I'm not sure why it would be throwing that error.

Comment: Function specifications for `GEN_1024_PRIME` and `RABIN_MILLER`(t = 4, k factor) should to be decorated with `impure`, also where they're declared (if different). Came across [Behavioral to Structural Conversion Problems VHDL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22047127/behavioral-to-structural-conversion-problems-vhdl) - contains a 32 bit implementation in  function `IS_Prime` which demonstrates a VHDL implementation of the Rabin Miller test. It's usually done structural in VHDL because big_num hardware is required in silicon.

Comment: @Ryan In VHDL, when doing arithmetic between `signed/unsigned` and integer value, the integer is casted to the same type and same length as the other operand. So `temp * 2` is equivalent to `temp * to_unsigned(2, temp'length)` which yield a result of 2048 bits. Mathematically, we know it's at most `1025` bits, so it's safe to drop the other bits.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I mis-read your comment earlier thinking that in the case of an overflow your solution would remove the extra bits.  Using `resize` makes sense and fixed the problem for me.

Comment: @Ryan You are right, my original comment would discard the MSB. The versions that does not are `temp_1025 := shift_left(('0' & temp), 1)` and `temp_1025 := resize(temp * 2, temp_1025'length)`. This version output the whole 1025 bits from the operation.